# how to read web.config key in Typescript

Tags: typescript

How can i get key value in angular2 application through typescript.

```
add key="localPath" value="http://localhost:618/"
add key="serverPath" value="http://api.azure.net/"
```

I want to get these value of "localpath" and "serverpath" in .ts file.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Because TypeScript is transpiled into JavaScript, you cannot read directly from a configuration file.

If you want to dynamically change URLs for a service (say from a DEV endpoint to a QA or Production endpoint), you can either use **Razor Syntax** in your HTML/CSHTML file to grab the value from the configuration file, and then *inject* the value into the scripts, **OR** you could use **Powershell** during deployment to replace the values in your TypeScript files during the build process.

```
# Argument passed into PowerShell script (or write out URL string manually).
$NewURL1 = $args[0];
$NewURL2 = "http://goodURL.com/api";

# *.js files, because your *.ts files will already be transpiled.
$files = gci "C:\MyProject\DropFolder" -recurse -include "exampleWithBadURL.js", "otherFile.js";

Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $fileContent = Get-Content($file) -Raw;
    attrib $file -r;

    # Perform the replacement.
    $fileContent -replace "http://localhost:38774/", $NewURL1 | Out-File $file;
    $fileContent -replace "http://badURL.com/api/", $NewURL2 | Out-File $file;

    Write-Output($file.FullName);
}
```

If your build/release agent allows it, you can run this Powershell script when deploying your code to a specific environment.  I use a similar script in **VSTS/TFS** in my release definition **after** I copy the files over.